# Automation Testing Of Tableau

Tags: selenium, testing, groovy, tableau-api

I am trying to automate the testing of tableau reports. So I am looking for some directions and framework that I can use for automation testing of Tableau using groovy, gradle and selenium. The tableau contains reports and charts which are not easy to test as it is difficult to locate the elements on the back end as they are in canvas. Any experience with this issue and the approach you are following will help me too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend looking into the spock testing framework and geb. For UI testing of web apps, geb is very helpful. Search for the Book of Geb.

See http://spockframework.org/ and 
http://www.gebish.org/

Since you are already using groovy, these should look very familiar. They are great tools. Spock works in a JVM world (so your app can use any JVM language). Use Spock for unit and integration tests. Geb works as a simulated web client (the system could be written in any language). Use Geb for end to end tests.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any books recommendations specifically for it?

Comment: Also are there any Github repositories for geb and spock I can see?